# Is there a way to scan barcodes/qr codes with device camera on windows using Fluent UI library in flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I was trying to make a barcode/qr code scanner for windows in flutter with fluent UI, but when i tried to google some scanning packages, there was nothing except some packages that use material library. I was woundering if there is a way to make a barcode/qr code scanner for windows in flutter with fluent UI.